# Separated React components linked by show/hide

Tags: reactjs

So I am putting together my first real React App and have a question:

I have a component I'll call Home. Inside Home are an arbitrary number of Graph components. Each Graph component has an icon the user can click to minimize the Graph. When the graph is minimized, an icon (possible a component) appears in its place that can be clicked to maximize it. This is done by toggling the state of the Graph. Currently the Minimized Icon just takes the position of the graph, but I now want that image to appear in an entirely different section of the Home Component. Is the best way to do this to put the minimized state in the Home component? How do I associate the Icon and the Graphs to minimize or maximize the correct Graph if so, especially if their could be many or few Graph components?

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question with-out seeing your code. But I would have a look at [react-overdrive](https://github.com/berzniz/react-overdrive) to add the minimize and maximize feature with routing. In the following [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/xrk25o8l74) you can see the simple routing example.

Comment: in your component before return you can put in a if(!show) return <some_btn_that_makes_show_action_into_true> and after that before your main return if(show) return()